# Load default value from HTML input to vue.js data

Tags: vuejs2

I wonder if it is possible to load value of tag `value` as default value for vue.js data?

Works fine with

```
coupon: $('#coupon').val(),
```

but I really do not want to use jQuery.

Code is available here: https://jsfiddle.net/4a80dnfo/1/

Comment: Can we use `v-scope` here?

Answer (score 7):

So I found a way to get this done using the `beforeMount()` hook.

Assuming this HTML:

```
<div id="coupon-code">
    <input ref="coupon" v-model="coupon" value="99PI_ORG" />
</div>
```

This Javascript should get the job done:

```
  new Vue({
    el: '#coupon-code',
    data: {
      coupon: ''
    },
    beforeMount: function() {
      this.coupon = this.$el.querySelector('[ref="coupon"]').value;
    }
    // methods and such here.
  }
});
```

I ended up using the `beforeMount()` hook after some trial an error.  Some things I've learned which may be relevant:

- `this.$refs` does not exist in the `created()` hook.
- `this.$refs.coupon.value` returns an empty string in the `mounted()` hook.
- The `ref` attribute of an element is deleted before the `mounted()` hook, so something like `this.$el.querySelector('input[ref=coupon]')` does not work.
- You can use `this.$el.querySelector('input[data-ref=coupon]').attributes['value'].value` inside `mounted()`, but this seems worse to me than using `beforeMount()`.

If anyone has suggestions on how to do this better, I'm very open to feedback.  This solution still feels sub-optimal to me.

Answer (score 6):

In your jsfiddle you are using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Text), so in your `data()` you just have to set your desired value

**Edit**: updated code to use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
            coupon: 'You value here',
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input id="coupon" type="text" name="coupon" :value="coupon" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this way, but I would like to pass data from html tag value instead of set it in Vue. Is it possible?

Comment: @KMatko i updated the asnwer. Use the 'v-bind:' or shorthand for it ':', but take note that you cannot mix it with v-model as it will be defeating the whole purpose of v-model (two-way data binding).

Answer (score 5):

```
<input  name="coupon"  v-model="coupon" value="def val">    

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#xxx',
    data: {
       coupon: document.querySelector("input[name=coupon]").value
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, a bit of explanation would not be bad.