# Input field default value in Vue.js

Tags: php, html, wordpress, vue.js

I have the following PHP+HTML form:

```
public function doContactForm() {
    ob_start();
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
<div id="vue_contact_form_app">
    <div class="basic-message" v-bind:class="{ 'error-message' : status == 'error', 'success-message' : status == 'sent' || status == 'sending' }" v-on:click="closeMessage">
            <p v-show="status != 'clean'">{{ actionMessage }}</p>
    </div>
    <form class="vue-form" @submit.prevent="submit">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="name">Your Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="" maxlength="80" v-model="name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="email">Your Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" required="" maxlength="40" :class="{ email , error: !email.valid }" v-model="email.value">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="An iteresting idea." required="" maxlength="120" v-model="subject">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label class="label" for="textarea">Message:</label>
                <textarea class="message" name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Dear Mr. Dmitry, ..." required="" v-model="message.text" :maxlength="message.maxlength"></textarea>
                <span class="counter">{{ message.text.length }} / {{ message.maxlength }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $this->getOption('PublicKey');?>"></div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the following Vue.js model:

```
function createVueContactForm(sendUrl) {
new Vue({
    // root node
    el: "#vue_contact_form_app",
    // the instance state
    data: function () {
        return {
            name: "",
            email: {
                value: "",
                valid: true
            },
            subject: "",
            message: {
                text: "",
                maxlength: 64 * 1024
            },
            status: "clean", //error, sending, sent
            actionMessage: "",
        }
    },
    
    computed: {
        hasMessage: function () {
            return this.status != "clean";
        }
    },
```

How do I set a default value for `Your Name` input field as `$current_user->display_name`?

Is there a better (or easier) way than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738184/load-default-value-from-html-input-to-vue-js-data)?

My first idea was that I do this [via HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76760969/assign-a-default-value-of-a-label-in-php-html), but it doesn't work.

See the full source code of my [WordPress plugin](https://github.com/dmitriano/vue-contact-form/blob/40657d7f65dcec869cec3ec03db765634fae7c3d/src/VueContactForm_Plugin.php#L139) (it is open-source)

Comment: You could read the value from the field (if you actually output it into there via your PHP code) when you are initializing the whole thing, something like `name: { value: document.querySelector('name').value, valid: true }`

Comment: @CBroe tried this: `name: { value: document.querySelector('name').value, valid: true },`, it without a success, probably `name` should be selected as `vue_contact_form_app->vue-form->name`? (I am to sure where is it in the document)

Comment: Did you actually pre-fill the field value via PHP?

Comment: @CBroe I hope, yes, see https://github.com/dmitriano/vue-contact-form/blob/40657d7f65dcec869cec3ec03db765634fae7c3d/src/VueContactForm_Plugin.php#L139 (the code is open-source)

Comment: @CBroe When I cleared the browser cache, the form disappeared, see https://developernote.com/contact/

Comment: @CBroe probably I have an old Vue.js version 2.5.16 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js ?